# MySQL Query Help, Group By Time, See if Record is in set

Tags: mysql

Quick question on how to do this, I'm unsure how it would work. Essentially I have a table with thousands of rows per day, and I want to group them by date for each row. That part is easy, but then I want to know if an instance is in that group, for example I want to know if Paul is on this date.

```
   Date      Name
 ------------------
| 4/8/2011 | Jack |
| 4/8/2011 | Jack |
| 4/8/2011 | Jack |
| 4/8/2011 | Jack |
| 4/8/2011 | Jack |
| 4/8/2011 | Paul |
```

I've got `SELECT count(*) as Total /*not sure what goes here*/ WHERE date = '2011-04-08' GROUP BY date`

Comment: Sounds like you'd rather know which groups were *present* on a certain date. Semantics, but it matters for the query.

Comment: Well, Paul will definitely there for the query, I just need to know if he's in each group or not.

Comment: Then currently, the answer from **taylonr** will create such a report. I am not sure if that's what you want, but I'm making assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select date, Count(*)
    , Max( Case When Name = 'Paul' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As HasPaul
From MyTable
Where date = '2011-04-08'
Group By date
```

Another approach where you simply look at whether PaulCount is > 0:

```
Select date
    , Sum( Case When Name = 'Jack' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As JackCount
    , Sum( Case When Name = 'Paul' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As PaulCount
    , Count(*) As OverallCount
From MyTable
Where date = '2011-04-08'
Group By date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Name FROM <TableName> Where date = <date desired> GROUP BY date, Name
```

This will group by date and then person, so there would be a 4/8/2011 group for Jack and one for Paul.